# Ruta de las carpetas demasiado largas en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Cuando estructuro mis carpetas me las marca como paquetes, que es algo usual en Java según recuerdo (Esto no  me da ningún problema en el proyecto). El problema entra cuando en este caso a cierto nivel me empieza a mostrar una ruta más larga desde read_qr (en este caso) hasta llegar al bloc específico de read_qr. ¿Cómo puedo mostrar únicamente el nombre de la carpeta sin que me mande toda la ruta? Este feature está sencillo pero hay otro en donde tengo 5 blocs y ahí ya cuesta saber cual es cual solo de vista y es medio confuso.

Investigando creo tiene que ver con la estructura de carpetas que configura Android Studio pero no se dónde modificarlas.

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

[image: Menú de opciones]

Answer (score 1):

En tu project explorer en el lado superior derecho hay un engrane,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

da clic en el engrane y selecciona `Tree Appearece` y desactiva `Compact Middle Packages`

[image: Jorgesys Android Studio Compact Middle Packages 1]

Al desactivar `Compact Middle Packages` podras ver tus directorios separados.

[image: Jorgesys Android Studio Compact Middle Packages 2]

Comment: Lamentablemente en un proyecto de Flutter no se puede usar esta opción. Agregué a la publicación original lo que me muestra

Comment: Ya veo, lo que sucede es que no estás usando Android Studio, yo lo uso con proyectos Flutter y si tengo esta opciòn.